# Как к сегодняшней дате правильно прибавлять количество месяцев?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Имеется код вывода сегодняшней даты(в формате 22.12.22)

```
const dateTime = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleTimeString('ru', {
    year: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit',
});
const date = dateTime.slice(0, 8);
```

Как к этой дате правильно складывать количество месяцев, чтобы по итогу получалась новая дата?
22.12.22 + 28(месяцев) = ?

Comment: Для начала ответить на вопрос, если сегодня 31 января и я хочу прибавить месяц, то какая дата получится?

Comment: понимаю. не может быть 31 февраля. Будет март разумеется, 3 или 4... не важно

Comment: `d = new Date(); d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 28); console.log(d)`

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь! Жаль не могу вас как-то отметить, Alexey